Is the principle of physical causal closure falsifiable?
From Wikipedia:

Physical causal closure is a metaphysical theory about the nature of causation in the physical realm with significant ramifications in the study of metaphysics and the mind. In a strongly stated version, physical causal closure says that "all physical states have pure physical causes" — Jaegwon Kim, or that "physical effects have only physical causes" — Agustin Vincente, p. 150.
Those who accept the theory tend, in general although not exclusively, to the physicalist view that all entities that exist are physical entities. As Karl Popper says, "The physicalist principle of closedness of the physical ... is of decisive importance and I take it as the characteristic principle of physicalism or materialism."
Definition
Physical causal closure has stronger and weaker formulations.
The stronger formulations assert that no physical event has a cause outside the physical domain — Jaegwon Kim. That is, they assert that for physical events, causes other than physical causes do not exist. (Physical events that are not causally determined may be said to have their objective chances of occurrence determined by physical causes.)
Weaker forms of the theory state that "Every physical event has a physical cause." — Barbara Montero, or that "Every physical effect (that is, caused event) has physical sufficient causes" — Agustin Vincente, (According to Vincente, a number of caveats have to be observed, among which is the postulate that "physical entities" are entities postulated by a true theory of physics, a theory of which we are ignorant today, and that such a true theory "will not include mental (or in general, dubious) concepts" (Note 5, p. 168).) or that "if we trace the causal ancestry of a physical event we need never go outside the physical domain." — Jaegwon Kim. Weaker forms of physical causal closure are synonymous with the causal completeness, the notion that "Every physical effect that has a sufficient cause has a sufficient physical cause." That is, weaker forms allow that in addition to physical causes, there may be other kinds of causes for physical events.
The notion of reductionism supplements physical causal closure with the claim that all events ultimately can be reduced to physical events. Under these circumstances, mental events are a subset of physical events and caused by them.

Does the principle of physical causal closure make testable predictions that could be shown to be false? In other words, is it falsifiable?

"Falsifiability" is a wrong standard that is no longer used (if it ever was) because any theory can be "saved" by suitable auxiliary "adjustments". Hence the references to what the best theories assert or will assert. But the causal closure of the physical is testable. For example, if our best theories interpret observations as, say, the outcome of quantum collapse being influenced by the 'mind' without detecting any physical substrate of such influence (as Penrose et al. suggest) then causal closure will be rejected.

Fifty seven questions, about half in the past month, that's about one a day. All to do with whether beliefs can be justified. What are you trying to prove? No beliefs are justified, at all, ever. That's not how things work. Otherwise, there would be no Stack Exchange, no schools, no politics. And no religion.

@Conifold your evidence that falsifiability is a “wrong standard” is pointing out criticisms of falsifiability? By that logic, everything is a wrong standard in philosophy since one can find criticisms of anything!

The OP's definition of causal closure is based on the concept of "physical causes", which is problematic since we don't have a definitive list of "physical causes". We don't know what counts as physical and what doesn't. Mental causes seem excluded in some authors, and not in others for instance. It's unclear what the principle rules out, and thus how it could be tested.
So maybe we need a better definition, because there's something potentially useful in causal closure. It says something important, like: "there's always a rational explanation." What is meant in the assertion that “physical events have physical causes” is "causes that we humans can apprehend and predict, at least to a degree, rationally." However, we do not need a perfect knowledge of the "ways of the world" to use the principle epistemologically. Even someone with no scientific culture at all can figure out something about the world. Even non-biologists know that cats can’t breed dogs. And if we were to witness a cat breeding dogs, even the non-biologists among us would be quite surprised.
But would we immediately abandon causal closure?
Some of us might, calling it a miracle, i.e. an obvious exception to the laws of nature attributable to a deity or another. But others would keep their faith in causal closure; they would still try and find a rational explanation for the phenomenon compatible with what we know of the laws of nature (e.g. a prank, or some odd mutation). And by looking for a rational explanation in terms of natural laws, they might actually find such an explanation, when the other guys who thanked God for the miracle will never find an explanation that they were not looking for.
Therefore, when understood epistemologically (as a general research principle), causal closure is potentially useful to resist the lazy temptation of "the gods of the gaps".
As a corollary, if and when used as a general research principle CC becomes untestable, unfalsifiable precisely because it functions as a fundamental belief, which we use to stimulate our search for naturalistic explanations and orient our testing. So even when faced with a blatant break in CC like cats breeding dogs, the believers in CC would still look for a naturalist explanation of it. They would NOT so easily abandon CC.
So far, that says nothing about the value of causal closure as an ontological commitment. To go there, deeper into metaphysics, I for one need a better definition.
The only definitions I found for CC in the SEP referred to "physical causes", a category which I find too vague as explained above. I considered Conifold's version: “microphysics do not change in collectives”. Then I started to wonder: what does change in collectives then? What accounts for, say, war between two nations, if microphysics cannot account for it? So I dropped the reference to microphysics as needlessly reductive. Then I looked at the OP's Wikipedia article and found this:

Causal closure attempts to reduce all teleological final (and formal) causes to efficient causes.

This is interesting because IMO those categories of causes -- final, formal, efficient -- are more precisely defined in philosophical literature than the term "physical cause". This terminology goes all the way back to Aristotle:
Wikipedia:

The four causes or four explanations are, in Aristotelian thought, four fundamental types of answer to the question "why?" in analysis of change or movement in nature: the material, the formal, the efficient, and the final.


What does it mean to say: "Causal closure attempts to reduce all final causes to efficient causes?" (leaving formal causes aside for the moment) It means, for example, that one's wishes and goals - our whole mental life of meaning, really, i.e. "the mind" - can in theory (according to causal closure) be explained or described as resulting from a series of production mechanisms that efficiently produced one's wishes and goals. It means that our mental life is the efficient product of our body (brain).
The principle does not exclude final causes from existence, it simply says: No final cause can exist without a series of efficient causes that produced it.
That would exclude ghosts, since their alleged thinking and meaning is not supported by a body able to produce it anymore. It also excludes pure spirits and immaterial gods, on the same ground.
If we adopt this formulation of the principle, we can derive from it a more precise notion of what kind of thing is excluded by causal closure: "pure teleology" without biology: the actions in this world of pure (unphysical) spirits such as ghosts or gods.
In summary, a belief in causal closure -- best defined as the idea that all teleological (final) causes can be reduced to efficient causes -- implies a disbelief in teleology not supported by any material system. In contrast, teleological causes supported by some material system (e.g. biological or electronic) are compatible with causal closure. There’s nothing magic with some computer software trying to win a game of chess, nor with a human trying to find something to eat, because their final cause or goal (to win, to eat) could be reduced to a series of efficient causes (respectively, computer programming and Darwinian evolution).
Finally, a word about formal causes, also listed in the Wikipedia entry as reduceable to efficient causes under CC. Aristotle stated, correctly IMO, that there's no matter without form and no form without matter. That's often seen as a materialist rebuttal of Plaro's ideal forms.
In Aristotelian ontology, material causes and formal causes are deeply intertwined, meaning that formal causes cannot be reduced to material causes or even to efficient (fabrication) causes. It is true that every form (or shape, or structure) taken by matter was "born" one day, it emerged or appeared historically at some point during the life of the universe, and will be destroyed (most probably) at another point. But forms emerge from prior forms, and evolve or change into new forms. Efficient causes transform forms into other forms. At no time does matter become formless in the process. Formal and material are two sides of the same "formateriality". There's no reduction from one to the other, nor to efficient causes.
Wikipedia's inclusion of formal causes (together with final causes) among the stuff that CC attempts to reduce to efficient causes is therefore unwarranted, at least under "the Aristotelian understanding".
Note how Aristotle's idea of "no form without matter" mirrors in a way the idea of "no final cause without efficient causes." But here's the twist: he also said "no matter without form"... Could we perhaps mirror that too in terms of: "no efficient cause without final cause"?
Could CC imply not just "No teleology without materiality," but also, vice-versa, "No materiality without teleology?"
In a way, yes: we've seen that belief in CC implies belief in some laws of nature, and in humankind's capacity to understand or at least approximate them. CC implies that efficient causes follow rules, a logic or logos inherent to the universe, which the role of science is to decipher. Naturalists may think of these rules or laws as aimless, meaningless, without purpose or goal, but the believer may ask: Who spoke this logos? Who wrote the rules of nature?

In principle of course it is falsifiable: all you have to do is to identify a physical event that provably has no physical cause. The problem in practice, however, lies in proving whether a cause is physical.

Like can something exist if it's not physical. An example of transition to existence can be that from non-physical 'transcendental' unconscious mind to impulses and tangible thoughts. This might seem overly mental, but there's plenty going on invisibly. A more preferable physical world answer, is it problematic that we don't know what we don't know about matter.

Kant addressed physical causality in his 3rd antinomy, concluding that cosmic causality is unfathomable.
As per my answer to Why is creationism even an issue? where The Critique of Pure Reason (A445/B473) is quoted in full.
In summary:-
Thesis: in an infinite regress of causes, eternal existence with infinite time can never elapse to arrive here & now, therefore some spontaneous event ('freedom') must have been able to happen.
Antithesis: a spontaneous event contradicts the principle of causality.
Both plausible, but contradictory.  (A dialetheism I presume.)

One should ask:

What are the relevant claims?
Where should the burden of proof rest?

Suppose we accept the existence of physical reality (if one doesn't, that would entail a different argument). Then a claim of the "non-physical" entails there being 2 states of existence: physical and non-physical.
One may reasonably ask: what do each of these categories mean, what belongs to each category, how do we differentiate them, how do we know any of this, etc.
I'd say it's the burden of anyone making non-physical claims to answer these questions, given that they're the ones trying to draw this categorical distinction, they're trying to say the non-physical is a coherent concept, and it's meaningfully distinct from the physical (and often beyond that, that there are non-physical things which actually exist).
Without them having met their burden, which they don't seem to have done - they mostly just try to shift the burden back onto physicalists... But anyway, without this burden having been met, a physicalist may just reject the coherence of the non-physical, in which case whether the physical has causal closure becomes a non-issue, since the physical would be all that we know to exist. This would functionally equivalent to the question of whether everything that exists has casual closure - is that a useful or meaningful question? Perhaps, in that it is useful to know what things cause other things (although at most, we're only really able to get to "we don't know what causes this"). But it doesn't seem to say much about physicalism vs non-physicalism.
* If one wants to say non-physicalism exists because of a lack of causal closure between 2 sets of things, it can't be dismissed as above. But then the question shifts to: how do you know there isn't causal closure? We could investigate how reasonable that claim is for what is being claimed - for consciousness, there is an exceedingly strong correlation between that and the physical brain, so the claim doesn't seem too reasonable on its face. One might also ask: it is meaningful to differentiate things as physical and non-physical based purely or primarily on a lack of causal closure between them? There doesn't seem to be causal closure between a distant star and most of what happens on Earth, but we say both are physical because they exist in the same physical space (and connected via indirect causal links). Even a physical particle that spontaneously pops into existence and disappears without affecting anything around it would probably still be defined as being physical. So causal closure doesn't seem to be the determining factor there.
Once one accepts the coherence of the non-physical, and one has a demonstrated non-physical thing, one could potentially test correlation between the physical and non-physical, while trying to eliminate confounding variables and using other common means to try to establish causation (you can't, strictly speaking, ever prove causation, but we reasonably infer it from a strong causation free from apparent confounding variables). Thereby, we might falsify physical causal closure. But we're still stuck at the first step of this, of establishing the coherence of the non-physical. And people do like to say that their pet non-physical claims can't be detected or investigated using empirical means, which would certainly throw a wrench into trying to using empirical means to investigate the link between physical and non-physical (but it also throws a wrench into the making of such a claim in the first place, because lack of empirical evidence raises the question of how such a claim could otherwise be justified, but that's a different question entirely).
Hempel's Dilemma?

The incoherence of physicalism is well known, and even has a name: Hempel's Dilemma

Incorrect. Similar to what I stated above, Hempel's dilemma ("it is quite unclear what is to be understood here by a physical phenomenon") presupposes that there are 2+ categories of things (physical and non-physical), and says physicalism draws a poorly-defined line that excludes one. But physicalism only posits that there is 1 category of things (physical). It only points to the incoherence of physicalism IF you presuppose the coherence of non-physicalism (which doesn't seem to hold). If someone wants to posit that there are 2 categories, it would be on them to explain what those categories are and differentiate and justify them.
Imagine a bag of marbles. One person looks inside, digs around, closely investigates a whole bunch of the marbles, and says "yeah, looks like a bag of marbles". Another person says: it is unclear what is to be understood here by "marble", the burden of proof is on you to prove that there isn't anything aside from marbles in the bag, it is incoherent to say there are only marbles in the bag. That would be a laughable response in that context, but a similar response is presented quite-seriously for the non-physical.
If you want to say there are non-marbles in the bag, point to them. If you cannot, one might posit whether those actually exist, or whether they're simply a figment of the imagination or a trick of the light, and we can investigate that. If you point to something that we agree exists, we can consider the molecular makeup of that versus everything else, to try to establish the marble vs non-marble distinction (which isn't really that vital to a "marblist", except for the fact that there doesn't seem to be anything besides marbles). But the non-marbles are typically specifically proposed to be outside of empirical investigation, outside of how we investigate marbles, and said to be made of things that are unlike anything we know, even though people cannot explain what those other things are that it is made of or how we can know that.
It's just a mess of circular reasoning and shifting the burden of proof: it proposes a poorly-defined category of non-marble, and then it implies that we cannot reject its existence because there is now a poorly defined line between marble and non-marble. And then it asks people who don't accept the existence of non-marbles to back up their non-acceptance by asking them to justify the distinction between marble and non-marble. And then people use this reasoning as support for their claims of the existence of specific things that they decided fits into this elusive "non-marble" category.

Regarding burden of proof, I would suggest that anyone who claims that metaphysical restrictions apply to reality would have the burden of proof resting on them. If someone says that reality is casually closed, that seems trivially true and doesn't really impose any restrictions on reality. If you define physicalism to mean "whatever reality is", that's fine but you are essentially watering down and trivializing the meaning of physicalism. However, if you define physicalism in a more restrictive  way and claim it to be true, you would have a burden of proof resting on you.

You would need to show that those restrictions actually hold in reality.

Zen Koan: Has the dog Buddha-nature? Physicalist Koan: Has the burden-of-proof Physical-nature?

@user80226 Is there anything that exists of type sahigoabpia? Does non-sahigoabpia have causal closure? If you want to define non-sahigoabpia as "whatever reality is", that's fine, but you are essentially watering down and trivialising the meaning of non-sahigoabpia. You might reasonably respond: please explain what in the world you're talking about, to make any of that make sense. That's also my response to claims of the non-physical. You can't place a burden of proof on someone to disprove what you haven't defined yet. You're essentially asking them to explain what you mean by your own claim

@NotThatGuy Sounds like you are suggesting we should get rid of the word physicalism entirely and simply talk about reality? Everyone would be happy to concede that reality is real, that's trivially true. So what's the point of coining the concept of physical reality if by physical we mean real? It's like saying "real reality". It's redundant.

In short, is your position that we should get rid of the label physical because that creates an unjustified and unexplained dichotomy between physical and non-physical, and instead we should simply talk about reality without attaching labels to it? Whatever is real is real, and that's it?

@user80226 Yes and no. I'd say we should get rid of non-physical, and all claims associated with it. At which point "physical" would become redundant (at least in this context - it's still useful in other contexts). People keep making poorly-defined claims of the poorly-defined "non-physical", so it is still useful to identify as someone who doesn't accept any of that, who doesn't think any that should be accepted. Like how if people keep saying sahigoabpia things exist, it is useful to indicate that you don't accept any of that, that no-one has defined what that even means.

It falls to the physicalist to prove that the concept burden of proof is physical!

The incoherence of physicalism is well known, and even has a name: Hempel's Dilemma.  One cannot define physicalism in any way that excludes what physicalists want to deny (Gods, spirits, math, other abstract objects) without the definition being demonstrably false.

@SystemTheory I wouldn't claim that "the concept burden of proof is physical", so I wouldn't accept the burden to prove that. Not really sure what that even means, and it may fall into a similar trap of presupposing the coherence of the non-physical, as per my answer. You can meet your burden of proof in whatever way you want (not purely through "physical" means). But do expect people to question why we should trust your method if try to back up your claim with a method unlike what we use (very successfully) for everything else.

@NotThatGuy - Physicalism holds that all things are physical or depend upon a physical substrate. If the burden of proof is a non-physical concept then it refutes physicalism. Or it provokes the search for the neural correlates of burden of proof concept. The moral effort to shift the burden of proof to those who recognize non-physical qualia and concepts is evidence that there are non-physical concepts including moral agents who seek to shift burdens of proof.

@SystemTheory Your point boils down "if the non-physical exists, then the non-physical exists". It's a fairly trivial point that doesn't refute anything I said. But I'm not too inclined to engage much deeper, since it seems like you're trying to play "gotcha" instead of wanting an honest and respectful discussion. I can only assume you singled out the burden of proof to try to make what I said sound silly, when your point works equally well (or poorly) for all concepts. And that you threw the word "moral" around (with no justifying context) to try to paint anyone who disagrees with you as evil

@NotThatGuy - Asserting that the burden of proof of non-physicalism lands on the other side refutes physicalism by evoking non-physical moral arguments. Accusing me of playing "gotcha" is another moral tactic that refutes physicalism. Pretending to be above moral behavior while engaging in such moral judgment is not inherently evil. I would characterize it as ignorance or some sort of intellectual false pride. I have models for moral argument, and moral agents, and models for physical systems, but physical reductionism does not explain moral agency or other non-physical attributes.

@SystemTheory I'll just leave my answer and earlier comments to speak for themselves.

All observations are physical interactions between a physical observer and a physical event.
Therefore anything you observe is by definition physical, and nothing you can observe can be non-physical.
So no, you cannot falsify physical causal closure.


no physical event has a cause outside the physical domain

Like you said, this is a metaphysical statement, really just a sequence of words, "language idling" as Wittgenstein might say, flatus vocis, "a puff of air"; a statement that happens to be both meaningless and irrelevant in physics, and therefore neither falsifiable nor confirmable.
But suppose, for the sake of argument, "toward contradiction" as some mathematicians would say, that the statement is falsifiable by a physics experiment. The experiment would then show a way to detect a cause (an event or entity) C for some event E such that C would be "outside the physical domain". But anything measured or detected by measurement, i.e. by sensorial evidence based on some physics experiment, is by definition (or by assumption) "inside the physical domain". Ergo, the statement is not falsifiable.
No amount of sensorial evidence can either "justify" or undermine that statement. You won't find it in any physical theories or descriptions of experiments. Physicists might utter those words -- when they are "off duty" as it were and make the unwise decision to go into discussion with creationists or with Cartesian dualists. But even then, it seems better not to use that kind of loose talk.

Since there is the belief that quantum indeterminacy is a counter example that falsifies causal closure, I want to write an answer to show that this counter example is still not found and that its strongest showcase, radioactive decay, is not in fact a valid counter example. For the philosophers here who object that this is not a physical question: there is a philosophical twist in the tail.
Causal closure means that there are no physical effects without physical causes (Montero).
Radioactive decay of Uranium is an effect that comes from the supernova event that brought the unstable Uranium nucleus into being. There is just an uncertainty in the time because the strong nuclear force stabilises the neutron in the nucleus. The fact that the decay, the effect, takes an inordinately long time (because of quantum tunneling), doesn't mean it didn't have a cause. Interestingly, free neutron decay is a matter of only minutes.
Very often, radioactive decay is almost instantaneously like the proton collisions in the Large Hadron Collider at CERN. Two particles collide and a plethora of other particles is the result. In this case it is clear what caused these particles because the cause and effect are almost instantaneous (fractions of a fraction of a second).
To see that the time is irrelevant, take the following example: If I throw a ball through a glass window then I am the cause of breaking that window. If I cause an asteroid out of its planetary orbit and it crashes  into a distant planet after a few million years, I am still the cause of that unfortunate incident. It just took a little longer and it was perhaps somewhat unpredictable.
The philosophical twist is that this thinking has a long history. The author is Edward Feser and I do not always align with his thinking but I think this exposé is lucid and worth reading.

[..] Scholastic philosophers have thought about local motion.  Some of these thinkers, and Aquinas in particular, take the view that a substance can manifest certain dispositions in a “spontaneous” way in the sense that these manifestations simply follow from its nature or substantial form.  A thing’s natural tendencies vis-à-vis local motion would be an example.  These motions simply follow from the thing’s substantial form and do not require a continuously conjoined external mover.  Now, that is not to say that the motion in question does not have an efficient cause.  But the efficient cause is just whatever generated the substance and thus gave it the substantial form that accounts (qua formal cause) for its natural local motion.  (It is commonly but erroneously thought that medieval Aristotelians in general thought that all local motion as such required a continuously conjoined cause.

The article has some more detail but I leave it here.


physical causal closure states "all physical states have pure physical causes"

I think that I want to lift up my hand and lo and behold my arm lifts. By the standards of mainstream physics this is a non-physical cause causing a physical cause. Physicalists, deny that that there is a problem here because they model the mind mechanically. Nevertheless this is hugely controversial.
I don't see how this principle differs from garden-variety physicalism. It is merely investigating its internal logic.

Is the principle of physical causal closure falsifiable.

No, it's not. It's a metaphysical assumption. This means its not scientific. And indeed its not as its a philosophical perspective on the natural world.

According to the Copenhagen interpretation of quantum mechanics the decay of a single radioactive atom has no cause.

The decay does not falsify the statement of Kim:  “No physical event
has a cause outside the physical domain”.
I expect falsifying the statement of Kim requires to establish magic.

But the decay falsifies the statement of Montero:  “Every
physical event has a physical cause.”



How is it proved that there is no cause?

@ChrisDegnen For an introduction see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copenhagen_interpretation "Features common across versions of the Copenhagen interpretation include the idea that quantum mechanics is intrinsically indeterministic, [...]."

I guess if all we can determine subatomically is based on probability then that’s as far as things exists, technically.

I don't think radioactive decay falsifies Montero's formulation. Please read my answer on this same question where I explain why.

@Philomath Heavy elements originated in cosmic explosions of previous stars. Your answer invokes supernova explosions, strong nuclear force, tunnel effect, LHC. All these do not identify a cause for the specific event, that a given U-238 atom decays now and not millions of years later. Quantum mechanics does not provide a cause, the indeterminism of the Copenhagen interpretation even denies any cause. – Why do you link to the blog of Feser? Which argumentative weight has Feser’s opinion concerning radioactive decay?  - Your answer blurs the distinction between Kim’s and Montero’s statement.

@ChrisDegnen Which arguments support your guess? Please elaborate and clarify a bit, thanks.

Morning Jo, Insofar as objective existence is what can be determined, then if quantum physics is the most basic physics then the physical world is indeterministic, at least until a new breakthrough shakes things up. This quote sums it up: "An outstanding characteristic of modern physics is the application of the principle that only that which is observable is significant." It reminds me of Parmenides: τὸ γὰρ αὐτὸ νοεῖν ἐστίν τε καὶ εἶναι "For thinking and being are the same." Thinking (supported by evidence) makes determinations makes existence. Undetermined things aren't (yet) existent.

@JoWehler Do you think there is a difference between determinism and causality?

@Philomath My understanding of determinism and causality is shaped by science: The paradigm for determinism is the differential equation together with some initial conditions, which uniquely determine the time development of the system in question. Uniquely means that the trajectories do not branch. - While causality poses the question: Why is there a state change at all? The principle of cause and effect claims that this question is senseful and has an answer. (1/2)

@Philomath The Copenhagen interpretation dismisses causality for single events on the quantum scale. But it does not dismiss determinism in the above sense, to describe nature successfully by differential equations. (2/2)

Yes, the time evolution of the wave equation is fully deterministic as described by the Schrödinger equation which as you correctly stated is a differential equation. The problem is what happens when the wave function collapses. Here we get at the famous quantum indeterminancy. But we are not concerned with determinism. I don't think causality poses a question: why is there a state change at all? Up until decay the  nucleus was in superposition of decay and not decay. The creation of the nucleus all that time ago was the cause for that superposition. (1/2)

The reduction of this superposition to decay is so the effect of the creation of the nucleus which was the cause. That the time is wholly indeterministic is irrelevant just as the length of the time. My response to your comment is delayed but is still caused by your comment, even if it takes a billion years...(2/2)
